# cout (standard output) in C++

Tags: c++

```
// my first program in C++

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Is `cout` an object?
If so, where is it instantiated? (I don't see something like "`new ....`")

Comment: You wrote "count". It's helpful to think of it as "c-out" as in "console out". Similarly, there's a "c-in".

Answer (score 7):

cout is a global object declared somewhere in <iostream>.

By the way, unlike in Java or C#, you don't need `new` to create an object. For instance, this will work:

```
std::string str; // creates a new std::string object called "str"
```

Comment: It's declared in `<iostream>` not necessarily defined there.

Answer (score 2):

The current C++ standard states (27.3/2):

> [...]The objects are constructed, and
>   the associations are established  at
>   some time prior to or during first
>   time an object of class 
>   `ios_base::Init` is constructed, and in
>   any case before the body of main 
>   begins execution. The objects are
>   not destroyed during program 
>   execution.

And from ([iostream.objects]/2:

> If a translation unit includes
>   `<iostream>` or explicitly constructs
>   an `ios_base::Init` object, these stream
>   objects shall be constructed before
>   dynamic initialization of non-local
>   objects defined later in that
>   translation unit."

In C++ parlance a translation-unit is nothing but a compiler terminology for a file and any/all headers which are included into that file.

Comment: Well, a file, and any/all headers which are included into that file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `cout` is an object. It's instantiated in `<iostream>` header file behind your back (together with some other streaming objects like `cin` or `cerr`) :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is initialize by C++ runtime library when your program startup.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` is an object. It's instantiated by the implementation during the startup of your program. That means that it can happen in the CRT DLL or in the code linked statically.

Answer (score 0):

Cout is part of the library you just instantiated in the header IOSTREAM.